# Registration page using PHP/MySQL not storing user values to database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am developing a website with User registration and login ,after completing the page configuration ,i tried to register it worked perfectly and later next day i tried to register but the page is not loading ,after filling in the data and if i click submit ,it reloads the same register page with no effect ,how to solve this problem

**SQL Query Processing code:**

```php
<?php
class User
{
    public $user_active = 0;

    private $clean_email;
    public $status = false;

    private $clean_password;
    private $clean_username;
    private $unclean_username;
    public $sql_failure = false;

    public $mail_failure = false;

    public $email_taken = false;

    public $username_taken = false;

    public $activation_token = 0;

    function __construct($user, $pass, $email)
    {
        // Used for display only
        $this->unclean_username = $user;
        // Sanitize
        $this->clean_email = sanitize($email);
        $this->clean_password = trim($pass);
        $this->clean_username = sanitize($user);
        if (usernameExists($this->clean_username)) {
            $this->username_taken = true;
        }
        else if (emailExists($this->clean_email)) {
            $this->email_taken = true;
        }
        else {
            // No problems have been found.
            $this->status = true;
        }
    }
    public function userPieAddUser()

    {
        global $db, $emailActivation, $websiteUrl, $db_table_prefix;
        // Prevent this function being called if there were construction errors
        if ($this->status) {
            // Construct a secure hash for the plain text password
            $secure_pass = generateHash($this->clean_password);
            // Construct a unique activation token
            $this->activation_token = generateactivationtoken();
            // Do we need to send out an activation email?
            if ($emailActivation) {
                // User must activate their account first
                $this->user_active = 0;
                $mail = new userPieMail();
                // Build the activation message
                $activation_message = lang("ACTIVATION_MESSAGE", array(
                    "{$websiteUrl}/",
                    $this->activation_token
                ));
                // Define more if you want to build larger structures
                $hooks = array(
                    "searchStrs" => array(
                        "#ACTIVATION-MESSAGE",
                        "#ACTIVATION-KEY",
                        "#USERNAME#"
                    ) ,
                    "subjectStrs" => array(
                        $activation_message,
                        $this->activation_token,
                        $this->unclean_username
                    )
                );
                /* Build the template - Optional, you can just use the sendMail function
                Instead to pass a message. */
                if (!$mail->newTemplateMsg("new-registration.txt", $hooks)) {
                    $this->mail_failure = true;
                }
                else {
                    // Send the mail. Specify users email here and subject.
                    // SendMail can have a third parementer for message if you do not wish to build a template.
                    if (!$mail->sendMail($this->clean_email, "New User")) {
                        $this->mail_failure = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                // Instant account activation
                $this->user_active = 1;
            }
            if (!$this->mail_failure) {
                // Insert the user into the database providing no errors have been found.
                $sql = "INSERT INTO `" . $db_table_prefix . "users` (
                        `username`,
                        `username_clean`,
                        `password`,
                        `email`,
                        `activationtoken`,
                        `last_activation_request`,
                        `LostpasswordRequest`, 
                        `active`,
                        `group_id`,
                        `sign_up_date`,
                        `last_sign_in`
                        )
                        VALUES (
                        '" . $db->sql_escape($this->unclean_username) . "',
                        '" . $db->sql_escape($this->clean_username) . "',
                        '" . $secure_pass . "',
                        '" . $db->sql_escape($this->clean_email) . "',
                        '" . $this->activation_token . "',
                        '" . time() . "',
                        '0',
                        '" . $this->user_active . "',
                        '1',
                        '" . time() . "',
                        '0'
                        )";
                return $db->sql_query($sql);
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**Config.php file for Register Processing**

```php
<?php
if (is_dir("install/")) {
    header("Location: install/");
    die();
}
require_once ("settings.php");

// Dbal Support - Thanks phpBB ; )
require_once ("db/" . $dbtype . ".php");

// Construct a db instance
$db = new $sql_db();
if (is_array($db->sql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name, $db_port, false, false))) {
    die("Unable to connect to the database");
}
if (!isset($language)) $langauge = "en";
require_once ("lang/" . $langauge . ".php");

require_once ("class.user.php");

require_once ("class.mail.php");

require_once ("funcs.user.php");

require_once ("funcs.general.php");

require_once ("class.newuser.php");

session_start();
// Global User Object Var
// loggedInUser can be used globally if constructed
if (isset($_SESSION["userPieUser"]) && is_object($_SESSION["userPieUser"])) $loggedInUser = $_SESSION["userPieUser"];
else if (isset($_COOKIE["userPieUser"])) {
    $db->sql_query("SELECT session_data FROM " . $db_table_prefix . "sessions WHERE session_id = '" . $_COOKIE['userPieUser'] . "'");
    $dbRes = $db->sql_fetchrowset();
    if (empty($dbRes)) {
        $loggedInUser = NULL;
        setcookie("userPieUser", "", -parseLength($remember_me_length));
    }
    else {
        $obj = $dbRes[0];
        $loggedInUser = unserialize($obj["session_data"]);
    }
}
else {
    $db->sql_query("DELETE FROM " . $db_table_prefix . "sessions WHERE " . time() . " >=   (session_start+" . parseLength($remember_me_length) . ")");
    $loggedInUser = NULL;
}
?>
```

**Register Page PHP Code**

```php
<?php
require_once ("models/config.php");

// Prevent the user visiting the logged in page if he/she is already logged in
if (isUserLoggedIn()) {
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}
/*
Below is a very simple example of how to process a new user.
Some simple validation (ideally more is needed).

The first goal is to check for empty / null data, to reduce workload here we    let the user class perform it's own internal checks, just in case they are missed.
*/
// Forms posted
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    $errors = array();
    $email = trim($_POST["email"]);
    $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    $confirm_pass = trim($_POST["passwordc"]);
    // Perform some validation
    // Feel free to edit / change as required
    if (minMaxRange(5, 25, $username)) {
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_USER_CHAR_LIMIT", array(
            5,
            25
        ));
    }
    if (minMaxRange(8, 50, $password) && minMaxRange(8, 50, $confirm_pass)) {
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PASS_CHAR_LIMIT", array(
            8,
            50
        ));
    }
    else if ($password != $confirm_pass) {
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_PASS_MISMATCH");
    }
    if (!isValidemail($email)) {
        $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_INVALID_EMAIL");
    }
    // End data validation
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        // Construct a user object
        $user = new User($username, $password, $email);
        // Checking this flag tells us whether there were any errors  such as possible data duplication occured
        if (!$user->status) {
            if ($user->username_taken) $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_USERNAME_IN_USE", array(
                $username
            ));
            if ($user->email_taken) $errors[] = lang("ACCOUNT_EMAIL_IN_USE", array(
                $email
            ));
        }
        else {
            // Attempt to add the user to the database, carry out finishing  tasks like emailing the user (if required)
            if (!$user->userPieAddUser()) {
                if ($user->mail_failure) $errors[] = lang("MAIL_ERROR");
                if ($user->sql_failure) $errors[] = lang("SQL_ERROR");
            }
        }
    }
    if (count($errors) == 0) {
        if ($emailActivation) {
            $message = lang("ACCOUNT_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_TYPE2");
        }
        else {
            $message = lang("ACCOUNT_REGISTRATION_COMPLETE_TYPE1");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

**HTML Register Form**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>
      Registration | 
      <?php echo $websiteName; ?>

    </title>
    <?php require_once("head_inc.php"); ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="modal-ish">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2>
          Sign Up
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div id="success">

          <p>
            <?php echo $message ?>
          </p>

        </div>

        <div id="regbox">
          <form name="newUser" action="
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>
"  method="post">

  <p>
    <label>
      Username:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>
      Password:
    </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>
      Re-type Password:
    </label>
    <input type="password" name="passwordc" />
  </p>

  <p>
    <label>
      Email:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
  </p>

                  </div>

                </div>



                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="new" id="newfeedform" value="Register" />
                </div>


                 </form>
                 </div>

                 <div class="clear">
                 </div>
                 <p style="margin-top:30px; text-align:center;">
                   <a href="login.php">
                     Login
                   </a>
                   / 
                   <a href="forgot-password.php">
                     Forgot Password?
                   </a>
                   / 
                   <a href="
<?php echo $websiteUrl; ?>
">
  Home Page
               </a>
                 </p>

               </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's an awful lot of code. To get started, figure out where the problem is. It can help to just add `echo` statements in various places you think code should be running, and see which ones actually get displayed. That will give you a sense of what code really ***is*** running, and thus where the problem lies.

Comment: thanks for the info ,...i just posted this whole code all because sometimes,it will help people to find the problem ..if i want to tell you the exact problem ..i try to register with one user and it worked perfectly and i tried to test it again next day it didn't work ...the problem is in register php code and html form ...i have one more doubt ,i added another table to the same database (it is not used here and it won't affect the registration form)will that be the problem for registration not to work !!thanks for your reply

Comment: adding tables to the database in use shouldn't being reflected to the code unless it has the same name as an existing table. Your explanation is unfortunately still vague. Try to trace down the source of your problem. It's an important step to troubleshoot.

Comment: Hey have you got the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

In your html file remove the `action` attribute of tag `form` or use `action = ""`. Donot use `$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]` as it is prone to extra scripts being run from your page.
Other than that, will check the code. Try using `echo` or `print_r` wherever possible to check what part is causing problem. Use `try-catch` for checking if the db returns errors in SQL.